# Android NDK: Assertion failure: TARGET_PLATFORM is not defined

Tags: android, android-ndk

When using NDK r5b, when I do a build in my jni directory using

```
$NDK_DIR/ndk-build
```

it works fine.  But When I switch to r6b (just by setting $NDK_DIR differently) and run that same command,  I get

```
/usr/local/android-ndk-r6b/build/core/setup-toolchain.mk:20: *** Android NDK:  Assertion failure: TARGET_PLATFORM is not defined    .  Stop.
```

What do I need to do differently in r6b that I didn't need to do in r5b?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to add this line to jni/Application.mk:

APP_PLATFORM := android-8

This is new to r6b.  (Not required in r5b or r6, just r6b.)

Comment: It would be good if you specify full path of this, because jni/Application.mk appears multiple times in the ndk

Comment: Ok, found it, it's the one in the project's (not sdk) jni directory.