# Android NDK developer

Tags: android, android-ndk, gdb

this may a little issue, i use the Eclipse with Android plugin to develop a NDK project, on my project of the Eclipse workspace, there are some files under the libs/armeabi folder, includs gdb.setup ,gdbserver and some *.so files.

the file gdb.setup content like below:

```
set solib-search-path ./obj/local/armeabi
directory C:/IODT/WP140/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include jni     C:/IODT/WP140/android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl/system
```

the directory assign to the android-14, how can i modify it to other android version? If i edit this file, it's no effect. it looks like some othe places control it, which file or configuration?

Comment: Try the solution described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290594/android-ndk-assertion-failure-target-platform-is-not-defined.

Comment: yes, just go through it, i indeed to assign the Android platform version in mk file, but why my gdb.setup "think" is the android-14...